# Convert excel formula and check each row value

Tags: r

I want to use this Excel formula:

```
=IF(C2>=70,1,IF(D2>=70,-1,IF(E2>=70,-1,IF(F2>=70,0,IF(G2>=70,-1,IF(H2>=70,1,IF(I2>=70,0,999)))))))
```

I hope to check each row value which is bigger than 70, then R will give the number for them and I can use the formula in the following row automatically.
Also,the value may be `NA`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that it is easy for others to help you.

Comment: Check out the ifelse command

Comment: Thanks,if I want to check each value in table. how to use for loop with ifelse to check the value automatically because I will have lots of data. I have found the information but I'm not really understand.

Comment: You may also want to check out the `case_when` function from the `dplyr` package. The code is more readable than nested `ifelse` statements. If you want more specific help for your particular problem, pls provide a reproducible example as per Ronak Shah's example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a at least a couple of ways of programming the function, which I show below. The first is to write several if/else statements and the second is to make one very large call to `ifelse()`.

Depending on how you are using the function you could call the function in a couple of ways as well. The first would be to use `apply`, which will then generate a vector of values computed based on the formula applied to the rows. Each element in the output will be from the corresponding matrix row. You could also compute the values row-by-row using a `for` loop. Depending on the size of the data you might want to compare the time of each of these methods to determine which is the fastest.

```
# function to evaluate all the if/else conditions
f1 <- function(x){

  if(x[3] >= 70 && is.na(x[3]) == F){
    out <- 1
  }else if(x[4] >= 70 && is.na(x[4]) == F){
    out <- -1
  }else if(x[5] >= 70 && is.na(x[5]) == F){
    out <- -1
  }else if(x[6] >= 70 && is.na(x[6]) == F){
    out <- 0
  }else if(x[7] >= 70 && is.na(x[7]) == F){
    out <- -1
  }else if(x[8] >= 70 && is.na(x[8]) == F){
    out <- 1
  }else if (x[9] >= 70 && is.na(x[9]) == F){
    out <- 0
  }else{
    out <- 999
  }
  return(out)
}

# function with a single large function call
f2 <- function(x){

  out <- ifelse(x[3]>=70&& is.na(x[3]) == F,1,ifelse(x[4]>=70&& is.na(x[4]) == F,-1,ifelse(x[5]>=70&& is.na(x[5]) == F,-1,ifelse(x[6]>=70&& is.na(x[6]) == F,0,ifelse(x[7]>=70&& is.na(x[7]) == F,-1,ifelse(x[8]>=70&& is.na(x[8]) == F,1,ifelse(x[9]>=70&& is.na(x[9]) == F,0,999)))))))

}

# sample data to test function
#               A    B  C  D   E   F   G    H  I
x <- matrix(c(  0,  0,  71, 0,  0,  0,   0,  0, 0,
                0,  0,  0, 70,  0,  0,   0,  0, 0,
                0, 10,  1,  0,  71, 0,  10, 90, 0,
               99,  0,  0, 69, 67, 90,  99,  1,  0,
                0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  70,  0,  0,
                0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,   0, 71,  0,
                0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,   0,  0,  72,
                0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,   0,  0,  1,
                NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 70,   0,  NA, 0,
                NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  NA, NA),nrow=10,ncol=9,byrow=T)

# method 1: using apply and avoiding loop, with timing
ptm <- proc.time()
out_f1_m1 <- apply(X=x,MARGIN=1,FUN=f1)
time_f1_m1 <- proc.time() - ptm

ptm <- proc.time()
out_f2_m1 <- apply(X=x,MARGIN=1,FUN=f2)
time_f2_m1 <- proc.time() - ptm

# method 2: using a for loop
out_f1_m2 <- rep(NA,nrow(x))
out_f2_m2 <- rep(NA,nrow(x))

ptm <- proc.time()
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  out_f1_m2[i] <- f1(x[i,])
}
time_f1_m2 <- proc.time() - ptm

ptm <- proc.time()
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  out_f2_m2[i] <- f2(x[i,])
}
time_f2_m2 <- proc.time() - ptm
```

Comment: Thank for your explanation.